# Creating a simpledialog with tk that has a variable number of inputs and then outputting them

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, simpledialog

Im trying to create a simpledialog box in which you can input numbers. The number of inputs however does depend on a dataset, technically people are using it to input rows into a dataset.

I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

Ive tried putting the 'e1' objects into a dictionary and then later using them however this gives an unknown option error

```
class MyDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):
def body(self, master):
    d2={}
    f={}
    for i in range(len(df_data_1.columns) -1 ):
        Label(master, text=df_data_1.columns[i]).grid(row=i)
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e1.grid(row=i, column=1)
        d2[df_data_1.columns[i]] = self.e1.get()

        print(d2[df_data_1.columns[i]])
    return self.e1
    print(self.e1)
    f[df_data_1.columns[i]]=self.e1
    return d2 # initial focus
    return f
    print(f)

def apply(f):
    for x in range(len(df_data_1.columns) -1 ):
        d2[df_data_1.columns[x]] = f[df_data_1.columns[x]].get()
        print(d2[df_data_1.columns[x]])
    first = d2
    print(first)

root = Tk()
d = MyDialog(root)
print (d.result)
```

Comment: When building your own custom dialog window its best to use `Toplevel()` and build it from scratch.

Comment: thx, but that is not the "main" problem. i need an option to create flexible variablenames, e.g. e1, e2, e3 and so on to actually save all the inputs. It just outputs None for now

Comment: @Mike-SMT: there's nothing wrong with inheriting from simpledialog.Dialog. It exists specifically for this type of situation.

Comment: @BryanOakley For what they are wanting to do it seams to me easier to build that functionality in a toplevel window. I guess it doesn't really matter if they build it in a class that inherits from dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the instances in a list. The problem with your code is that you overwrite `self.e1` on every iteration of the loop.

It would look something like this (untested, since you didn't give us code we can run to duplicate the problem):

```
self.entries = []
for i in range(len(df_data_1.columns) -1 ):
    Label(master, text=df_data_1.columns[i]).grid(row=i)
    entry = Entry(master)
    entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
    self.entries.append(entry)
```

You can later iterate over all of the entries like this:

```
for entry in self.entries:
    value = entry.get()
    print("value:", value)
```